# Unable to run grunt-karma

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, karma-runner

I am trying to use grunt-karma (https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-karma) with this config:

```
karma:
      unit:
        runnerPort: 9999
        singleRun: true
        browsers: ['PhantomJS']
        logLevel: 'ERROR'
        background: true
        files: [JASMINE, JASMINE_ADAPTER, 'test/server/*.js']
```

The gruntfile is written in coffeescript. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
>grunt karma:unit
Loading "Gruntfile.coffee" tasks...ERROR
>> ReferenceError: JASMINE is not defined
Warning: Task "karma:unit" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

The configuration sample (on the npm page linked to above)does not show any requirements to define JASMINE, so I'm confused what it is that I am not doing right.

Please help me fix this.

(Additionally, can you advise me of alternative ways to test nodejs + expressjs projects using grunt and jasmine)

Comment: `files: [JASMINE, JASMINE_ADAPTER, 'test/server/*.js']` what does your `JASMINE` and `JASMINE_ADAPTER` meant to be??

Comment: I am just trying to use the directions provided on that page. https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/v0.8.5/test/client/karma.conf.js So I'm assuming JAMSINE and JASMINE_ADAPTER would have been defined.